# Run a Zend1 app on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I need to run a zend1 app on my local system which is working on a production server successfully.

The problem I'm facing currently is that when I run it through `localhost/example` it shows me nothing, just a blank page and when I try to call a controller directly like `localhost/example/controller1` it moves to 404.
I've searched the issue on Google and tried to implement all the possible solutions, but no luck.

Here is the `.htaccess` of the app

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^media\/\.cache\/(.*)$ image.php?file=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\/\\\-]+)?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: have a look at your RewirteCond *RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com [NC]* there is your problem by using it on **localhost**

Comment: I can't understand this syntax, can you please tell me, what does it mean? and what it should be for **localhost**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write to much things in .htaccess.
you can use this few line code for .htaccess file.
and you need to put this .htaccess file and index.php file on root folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
Options -Indexes
```